# php bitrix область видимости $this

Tags: php, битрикс

в файле `/bitrix/component/advertising.banner/templates/bootstrap_v4/template.php` содержится такая запись:

```
<? $this->addExternalJs("/bitrix/components/bitrix/advertising.banner/templates/bootstrap_v4/bxcarousel.js") ?>
```

разве `$this` может существовать вне класса? `var_dump` показывает данные есть. Также не понятно: любая строка, в т.ч. и пустая не меняет поведение метода.

Comment: А кто сказал что код вне класса?

Comment: А кто сказал, что он внутри класса?

Comment: Раз используется this, значит вы в методе класса.

Comment: Что вам мешает в методе класса сделать `include`?